# can't delete a printer - how do I access the printing dialog with admin privileges?

Tags: 12.04, printing

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. When I access the "printing" menu (System settings / printing), and right-mouse-click on a printer, a number of options are disabled (rename, delete). Do I have to somehow access that screen with `sudo` and how ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
sudo system-config-printer
```

Comment: still disabled, same as before.